# Kendo UI/jQuery click event running multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm using Telerik's jQuery software called Kendo UI, to create a modal popup window. I'm having a rather odd problem with a Kendo modal popup box, which contains a `"Confirm"/"Cancel"` confirmation.  The first time I open the confirmation window & click either button (Confirm or Cancel), the window works correctly. The 2nd time I open this popup window & click a button, my Kendo's `click` event fires twice.  The third time I open the window, the click event fires 3 times, etc.  I can't figure out why.  It should only be firing once.

Here's my JS code.  The click function that's firing twice is in both the Confirm & Cancel sections, beginning on the line that reads `.click(function () {` :

```
var kendoWindow = $("#delete-confirmation").kendoWindow({
    title: "Confirm",
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    center: true
});

kendoWindow.data("kendoWindow")
    .center().open();

kendoWindow
    .find(".delete-confirm")
    .click(function () {
        kendoWindow.data("kendoWindow").close();
        destroyItem();
    })
   .end();

kendoWindow
    .find(".delete-cancel")
    .click(function () {
        kendoWindow.data("kendoWindow").close();
    })
   .end();
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: They are firing twice because you are binding to them twice. Either the elements don't actually get destroyed, or you are running the code you posted more than once on each click.

Comment: LOL, no offense, but this is what happens when some silly's think they'll reinvent the wheel. Honestly, I only ever stray from jQuery Basic to get jQueryUI (tried tested and provided from the same people as jQuery) and jQueryMobile(again, same people). Sometimes I might grab the occasional plugin, but for most things, the basic jQuery Libs have everything you need and function as expected. It looks like kendo is trying to copy jQueryUI's model dialgo function, which is also found in jQueryMobile. Just a hint, that same code, with jQueryMobile's .dialog, will work as expected every time.

Comment: Thanks @SpYk3HH, that's good to know.  jQuery's still relatively new to me & my boss asked us to use this Kendo UI.  Going forward, I'll look more into jQuery UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you should initialize your dialog only once (create it and add your handlers). Then every time you need the dialog to show you only call your

```
kendoWindow.data("kendoWindow").center().open();
```

line of code. It looks like each time you go to open the dialog its adding a new click hanlder and the previous handlers and the new handler will all be called on the click event.

Comment: Yeah, it turned out I was adding a new click handler.  This code was outside of my document.ready, in a separate function call.  I moved it into my document.ready & it works fine now.  Thanks