# Kendo ui click event fires multiple times

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

i have problem while using kendo ui dialog window. When i open kendo dialog window second time, and click accept button, event fires two times, next time it fires three times and so on. 
There is working example http://jsfiddle.net/T89mG/74/.
Where i made a mistake?

```
    addToQueueWindow = $("#AddToQueueWindow").kendoWindow({
    modal: true,
    visible: false
}).data("kendoWindow");

$(document).ready(
     $("#showAddMessageDialog")
    .button()
    .click(function (e) {
        addToQueueWindow.center().open();
        addToQueueWindow.wrapper
            .find(".add-confirm,.add-cancel")
            .click(function (e) {
                if ($(this).hasClass("add-confirm")) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("AddToQueueHandler", "ManageMessageState")',
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: { Id: $("#MessageidInput").val() },
                   complete: function (event, ui) {
                       $("#QueueContentGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                   }
               });
           }
                addToQueueWindow.close();
            });
    })
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog widget's DOM elements are created when you call `.kendoWindow()`, but every time you click your button to open the window, you add another `.click()` handler to the buttons in the window. Those DOM elements aren't removed when the window is closed. They are just hidden. So you are adding multiple click handlers to the same DOM elements.

You should move:

```
addToQueueWindow.wrapper
        .find(".add-confirm,.add-cancel")
        .click(function (e) {
```

Outside of your click handler for the open window button. Just do it once after the call to `.kendoWindow()`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should initialize your dialog only once (create it and add your handlers). Then every time you need the dialog to show you only call your

`kendoWindow.data("kendoWindow").center().open();`

line of code. It looks like each time you go to open the dialog its adding a new click hanlder and the previous handlers and the new handler will all be called on the click event.

Stolen from **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651828/kendo-ui-jquery-click-event-running-multiple-times)** to help :)

Comment: I initialize dialog window only once, and return it to addToQueueWindow variable.

Answer (score 0):

follow CodingWithSpike, I was edit your code and worked:

```
addToQueueWindow = $("#AddToQueueWindow").kendoWindow({
        modal: true,
        visible: false
    }).data("kendoWindow");

addToQueueWindow.wrapper
                .find(".add-confirm,.add-cancel")
                .click(function (e) {
                    if ($(this).hasClass("add-confirm")) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("AddToQueueHandler", "ManageMessageState")',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: { Id: $("#MessageidInput").val() },
                            complete: function (event, ui) {
                                alert("Complete");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    addToQueueWindow.close();
                }).end();

$("#showAddMessageDialog")
            .click(function (e) {
            addToQueueWindow.center().open();
        });
```